# Stuck with schedulable class

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I found some documentation for scheduling apex jobs, but I'm a little stuck. I made a class that does what I want to be scheduled; it is called setInterest(). Here is what I have so far in the schedulable...

```
global class scheduledInterestCheck implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {

        setInterest interest = new setInterest();

  }

}
```

What is that parameter?

Also, I saw part of the documentation had...

```
scheduledMerge m = new scheduledMerge();
String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('Merge Job', sch, m);
```

So it looks clear that something is calling the scheduled class, and setting the frequency it should be scheduled to. Where does this bit go?

Comment: It's a good practice to create a function (or three) for scheduling a class.  That way, there's no need to always be looking up the parameters.  I'll see if I can find an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add a touch more to Adrian's answer if I may, I'd like to give some context to this code that you've read:

```
scheduledMerge m = new scheduledMerge();
String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('Merge Job', sch, m);
```

Specifically, what does `system.schedule('Merge Job', sch, m)` do?

`System.schedule` is, as you've identified, a more complex method of scheduling a class and takes 3 parameters:

#### First Parameter

The first parameter is the name. This is used more as a description but at the time of execution, the name must be unique otherwise you'll get an error akin to the following:

> Scheduled job 'MyScheduledJob' threw unhandled exception.
>
> caused by: System.AsyncException: The Apex job named "MyScheduledJob'" is already scheduled for execution.

This may or may not be a good thing.

#### Second Parameter

This is the string you set here: `String sch = '20 30 8 10 2 ?';` and is known as a "Cron Expression". This is constructed by:

1. Seconds
2. Minutes
3. Hours
4. Day of Month
5. Month
6. Day of Week
7. Year (Optional)

There's also some special characters, I'd highly recommend reading up on this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm). Basically, this tells the scheduler how often it should run. Here's a table from that documentation that explains it a bit better:

```
Expression          Description
0 0 13 * * ?        Class runs every day at 1 PM.
0 0 22 ? * 6L       Class runs the last Friday of every month at 10 PM.
0 0 10 ? * MON-FRI  Class runs Monday through Friday at 10 AM.
0 0 20 * * ? 2010   Class runs every day at 8 PM during the year 2010.
```

#### Third Parameter

The final parameter is the class itself that you want to execute! In this case, it's a class called `scheduledMerge`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I am actually pretty okay with understanding what it is, I'm more confused about where it goes. Is there another class I'm missing? In my mind, there is the class that does the work, the class implementing shedulable interface that you schedule as a job that calls the first class. However, that code seems to be calling the scheduled class....so there's a third one,....?

Comment: @AdrianLarson's answer covers how to do that using the UI. But to make a class available for scheduling you need to implement schedule. Something like this:  `global class MySuperCoolScheduleClass implements Schedulable {` followed by your batch class code. Then, you can either do what Adrian has said in his answer, or use the Developer Console, `Debug > Open Execute Anonymous Window` and paste in the code you've got in your question or a variation of it.

Comment: Thanks for following up -- I'm sure I'm just missing one silly thing, but if you look at my code from my question, I have the implements schedulable class. What am I missing? It doesn't show as an option when I go to the UI through setup and try to find it as a class.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Ah I see, you're instantiating the class `setInterest()` but not telling Salesforce to do anything! I think the line you're missing is: `Database.executeBatch(interest);`

Comment: Oh! I think I understand. So sorry if I'm being really thick, but I still don't have a clear top-level overview on the pieces so I have to ask, where does the Database.execute(interest); go?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Editted the Answer. :) It was also `Database.executeBatch` is what I meant!

Comment: Oh I see thanks -- so I think I'm getting into more uncharted territory now, because I got the following "Argument must be an object that implements Database.Batchable". My setInterest class isn't anything special. I don't want to keep a thread going too long, but I think a top-level understanding of what's going on and what's needed would tie this up better! The Apex Scheduler documentation just doesn't do it for me...

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis It may well depend on what your class does. Should it be scheduled?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I've tried many other concepts but for my purpose, this is the most practical, and I think even the most possible....I have orders with a 30 day pay period, and if it has been 30 days, they should be charged interest. I've tried countless workflow concepts, formula fields...I'm definitely going this route, to check every day if orders where payment due > 0 and due date == today, add the interest

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis In which case, I'd look at a Batch class then as it happens. That may not be the best way, but it's the route I'd take. That'd be a different question entirely I think, but it sounds like you're on the right lines.

Comment: N.B. `global` is not necessary, `public` will do unless you are doing managed package

Answer (score 2):

**Parameter Meaning**

As for your first question the [`SchedulableContext`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_system_schedulablecontext.htm) interface:

> Represents the parameter type of a method in a class that implements the Schedulable interface and contains the scheduled job ID. This interface is implemented internally by Apex.

**How To Schedule**

Unless you are making a complicated schedule (more frequently than once daily), just schedule it through the UI. Go to `Setup` > `Develop` > `Apex Classes`, and click on the <kbd>Schedule Apex</kbd> button.

[image: Apex Classes Buttons]

If you want to do a more complicated schedule than once at the same time each day (or on certain days of the week), then you can schedule the class via `Execute Anonymous` where you would paste a script similar to what you shared in your OP. Make sure the CRON expression (your `sch` variable) is correct before you actually run it.

Comment: oh, wow! Thanks! I'll give it a try, that seems much easier.

Comment: Is the end date field when it should stop scheduling? I kind of want it to be scheduled daily indefinitely, unless it refers to something else..

Comment: Yeah, that's one downfall of the UI is you do have to set an end date. But you can set it many years out.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis  N.B. Sometimes, in order for the schedulable class to even show up as a candidate for scheduling - even though it implements the schedulable interface, you have to use DC or the UI to Run Tests for that class's testmethod

Comment: That's what I was coming back to ask, actually. I am searching for the class and I cannot find it. I'm in the "Schedule Apex" window from setup. What does DC refer to?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis DC = Developer Console.

Comment: You mentioned needing that for tests....how come I can't see it in the list of classes to use?

Comment: He's saying you need to run tests against it before you can schedule it (sometimes). Did you write a test for it? Have you run it?